# Problem with excel sheet upload into sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I need to upload excel sheet in to the database. Which i am doing with the query

```
SELECT * INTO temp FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\l.varada\Desktop\BA-Control.xls',
    'SELECT * FROM [qry_BA_Controlling (Report)$]')
```

Here C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\l.varada\Desktop\BA-Control.xls is the path from where the excel file needs to be fetched.
qry_BA_Controlling (Report) is the name of the worksheet.

So on executing the query, a table with name 'temp' is created. With records that are populated from excel.

Now here i have a date field in excel. sometimes the values of this field are not uploaded properly into the temp table. The values for this date field are set to NULL eventhough they have values in EXCEL.

**EDIT**
I have modified my query so,

```
Insert into temp Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
    'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\l.varada\Desktop\BA-Control.xls',
     HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [qry_BA_Controlling (Report)$]')
```

Here temp is an existing table, i have defined the date type of the field [creation date] to varchar and uploaded the excel. Then i used **convert** to change the datatype to the correct format..

```
update temp set [Creation date] = CONVERT (varchar,[Creation date],101)
```

Even now it is populating NULL values..Or this conversion needs to be done while uploading. if so, please let me know.

I think the reason behind this is, the first few values of this column are spaces and after that it has values..As it determines the datatype by checking first few rows..Then it is assigning NULL..Please suggest me an alternative.

Comment: Have you tried using the GUI? I used to have lots of problems with openrowsets and the GUI was a quick fix.

Comment: I have searched in net to import excel data into sql server using GUI. It is routing me to some shareware code where i need to pay.
Can you please explain in detail or please provide me a link.

Comment: Just google "sql server Data Import/Export Wizard" ;)
For example, see this: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3580216/SQL-Server-2005-Import--Export-Wizard.htm

Comment: Thanku for the response. It will not help me as end user needs to upload the excel sheet on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the query so, now it is able to import the data from excel.

EXEC('SELECT * INTO temp FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'',
''Excel 8.0;Database=' + @ba_bm_status + ';HDR=YES;IMEX=1'',' +
 '''SELECT * FROM [qry_BA_Controlling (Report)$]'')');

I have included IMEX=1, which tells the driver to use import mode.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly beware this approach will not work on x64 editions of SQL Server as there is no x64 MS Excel driver available.  I've seen people get caught out with this when writing something on 32bit and then deploying to x64 in production.

You're using a SELECT INTO which I think means that the Excel driver is looking at the first 100 rows (or similar) and determining that this field is a date.

I think it's most likely that SQL Server is then getting the date format wrong, you may find that the values that are NULL are ones that don't conform to US datetime formatting.  So we (Europeans) would accept 31/7/2010 however this is unacceptable MM/dd/yyyy format.

My suggestion would be to pre-define the temp table with all fields either int, float, or varchar.  Then manually convert them (using a view if convenient) to the correct types.  If I am correct about the date format being the issue you can use the CONVERT function to force the correct date format to be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! Please see the question edited and let me know if i can do anything further.

Comment: Ok, getting closer.  It's difficult to guess exactly without seeing the data, however I think your CONVERT statement is wrong.

update temp set [Creation date] = CONVERT (datetime,[CreationDateAsVarChar],101) 

You should be inserting the Excel file in to a table where ALL fields are varchar.  Then convert them in to a separate table with the correct types.